# I'm not sure this is a counting question or a probability question. Maze problem.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So here is the complete question:

Suppose you are trying to negotiate a maze and you are stuck with a
number of choices:

• Option A takes you to the exit in 5 minutes,

• Option B returns you to your current position after 3 minutes,

• Option C takes you to the exit in 8 minutes, and

• Option D returns you to your current position after 2 minutes.

(a) Suppose you make your choice uniformly at random, and if you return
to your current position you are unable to recall any of your previous
choices, so you always choose from all four options. What is your
expected time for exiting the maze?

(b) Suppose now you can remember any choice which returned you to
your current position and you choose uniformly at random from
your unexplored options. What is your expected time for exiting the
maze?

What I do know is that I should use permutations on (a) and r-permutations on (b) but I just don't know how to do it step by step. And how about the time of each option, do they mean weighted?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever tried writing up one of those equations where you say that the expectation value is equal to some expression, which also involves the expectation value? Try doing that.

Comment: You can analyse in terms of states if that helps you to get your head round things. There are two states - in the maze (M) and solved (S). Let the expected time to S from M be T. The expected time from S to S is zero, of course - S is a terminal state. Now what do the options you are given do (a) to the state and (b) to the time. Then use the fact that the four options are equally likely to combine them into a single equation. There are more states in the second part because the information you already know is part of the state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $T$ denote the time needed and write $\mu$ for $\mathsf ET$.

(a)

Then: $$\mu=\frac14\cdot5+\frac14\cdot(3+\mu)+\frac14\cdot8+\frac14\cdot(2+\mu)$$
This equation enables you to find $\mu$.

(b) Here we write $\mu_B$ for the expectation under the condition that option $B$ is not an option anymore. Likewise for $\mu_D$.

Then:
$$\mu=\frac14\cdot5+\frac14\cdot(3+\mu_B)+\frac14\cdot8+\frac14\cdot(2+\mu_D)$$

Now we can find expressions of the same sort for $\mu_B$ and $\mu_D$.

You are introduced in this now, so try this yourself.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer, but I just wonder the answer in (a),  it just means that the expected time = time that all options needed?

Comment: No, it is $\mathbb ET=\sum_{R\in\{ A,B,C,D\}}\mathbb E(T\mid R)P(R)$ where e.g. $A$ stands for the event that at the first time option $A$ is chosen.